# How to create random seed to have different results at each simevents run???(random seed?)

Tags: matlab, random, simulink, random-seed, simevents

I would like to generate different seed at each time to have various outcomes ... I have tried "shuffle," however it showed that "it is not supported!" Wish someone can help me!Thank you~

This is my settings:
[image]. 
It makes my simulation to end with the same outcome every time.

Comment: You can set a seed based on the current time.

Comment: Thanks! I have figured out the method :)

Comment: Can you create an answer yourself and mark it as correct? Other people with the same question may benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a random number by writing a code in the model properties "callback." Then, take it as a reference for your seed to generate the random seed.